# What is the meaning of this Khalil Gibran quote?

Tags: quote

I am reading "The Prophet". I am not clear about the below quote.

> Life is indeed darkness save when there is urge, and all urge is blind
>   save when there is knowledge, and all knowledge is vain save when
>   there is work, and all work is empty save when there is love.

I am not exactly sure about the meaning of "save".

I need help understanding the whole paragraph.

Comment: [It means except](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/save#Preposition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As curiousdannii suggests try replaying "save" with "except".

---

Here is the original passage from [Chapter 7, "On Work"](https://archive.org/details/KahlilGibranTheProphet_201903/page/n13):

> And I say that life is indeed darkness save when there is urge.
>   And all urge is blind save when there is knowledge.
>   And all knowledge is vain save when there is work.
>   And all work is empty save when there is love.

To help understand it better, I replaced "save when" with "unless":

> And I say that life is indeed darkness **unless** there is urge.
>   And all urge is blind **unless** there is knowledge.
>   And all knowledge is vain **unless** there is work.
>   And all work is empty **unless** there is love.

Here is a paraphrase of the above without line breaks:

> Without urges life is darkness. Without knowledge urges are blind. Without work knowledge is vain. And without love work is empty.

---

Gibran, K. The Prophet. 1923.   Retrieved on June 29, 2019 from *Internet Archive* at https://archive.org/details/KahlilGibranTheProphet_201903/page/n13